# Branch coverage with JUnit and Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, cobertura

I am writing a test case using `JUnit` API for a method. I've covered all the scenarios but the one that is giving me a hard time is in the `if` block. When I hover over this line the `Cobertura` states 50% 50% for each condition but I am not exactly sure how to get this covered.

Method under test:

```
protected boolean isDateWithinTimelineRange( Calendar date, ServiceContext ctx ) {
    Calendar end = (Calendar)ctx.getParameter( ServiceConstants.TIMELINE_END );
    Calendar start = (Calendar)ctx.getParameter( ServiceConstants.TIMELINE_BEGIN );

    if( end != null && start != null ) {
        if( date.getTimeInMillis() >= start.getTimeInMillis() && date.getTimeInMillis() <= end.getTimeInMillis() ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

JUnit test case:

```
@Test
public void testIsDateWithinTimelineRange() throws Exception {
    ServiceContext context = Mockito.mock(ServiceContext.class);
    Calendar calender = Mockito.mock(Calendar.class);

    Mockito.when(context.getParameter(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(calender);

    TestBaseTimelineProvider provider = new TestBaseTimelineProvider();
    boolean answer = provider.isDateWithinTimelineRange(calender, context);

    assertNotNull(answer);
    assertTrue(provider.isDateWithinTimelineRange(calender, context));

    // Testing for NULL condition
    context = Mockito.mock(ServiceContext.class);
    calender = Mockito.mock(Calendar.class);
    Mockito.when(context.getParameter(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(null);

    provider = new TestBaseTimelineProvider();
    answer = provider.isDateWithinTimelineRange(calender, context);

    assertNotNull(answer);
    assertTrue(provider.isDateWithinTimelineRange(calender, context));

    // Start date set to null
    context = Mockito.mock(ServiceContext.class);
    calender = Mockito.mock(Calendar.class);
    ServiceConstants constants = new ServiceConstants();

    Mockito.when(context.getParameter(ServiceConstants.TIMELINE_END)).thenReturn(calender);

    provider = new TestBaseTimelineProvider();
    answer = provider.isDateWithinTimelineRange(calender, context);

    assertNotNull(constants);

    // End date set to null
    context = Mockito.mock(ServiceContext.class);
    calender = Mockito.mock(Calendar.class);
    constants = new ServiceConstants();

    Mockito.when(context.getParameter(ServiceConstants.TIMELINE_BEGIN)).thenReturn(calender);

    provider = new TestBaseTimelineProvider();
    answer = provider.isDateWithinTimelineRange(calender, context);

    assertNotNull(constants);
}
```

What confuses me is the parameter `date` that I am mocking and which determines the values for the `end` and `start`variables.

`if( date.getTimeInMillis() >= start.getTimeInMillis() && date.getTimeInMillis() <= end.getTimeInMillis() ) {}` is the line that I want to cover.

Thanks

Comment: Don't you need to tell the mock what to return in the method `getTimeInMillis()`, for example:
`Mockito.when(calender.getTimeInMillis()).thenReturn(1L);` and work off that?

At the moment, calling `date.getTimeInMillis()` returns nothing as the `date` object was mocked, but nothing was set to be returned for your `getTimeInMillis()` method

Comment: You covered two cases when that returns true, but never covered the (two) cases when that returns false (first item not true, or first item true and second item not true). You should have at least one, and probably two cases where you assertFalse(provider.isDateWithinTimelineRange) with valid tests for that condition.

Comment: Yeah, actually I was debugging through it so got those two similar test cases. I am working on the getTimeMillis().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you never told your mocked calendar objects what to do when `getTimeInMillis()` is called.  You need to add the following for each calendar entry:

```
// Assume `long desiredlong` defined;
Mockito.when(calendar.getTimeInMillis()).thenReturn(desiredlong);
```

You will need to do this for a set of calendar objects where the date.getTimeInMillis() is in the desired range, and another set where date.getTimeInMillis() is outside the desired range.

Ultimately, a case that covers the true side of that test would take the form:

```
@Test
public void validDatesInRange() {
    ServiceContext context = Mockito.mock(ServiceContext.class);
    Calendar calenderstart = Mockito.mock(Calendar.class);
    Mockito.when(calendarstart.getTimeInMillis()).thenReturn(1L);

    Calendar calendertarget = Mockito.mock(Calendar.class);
    Mockito.when(calendartarget.getTimeInMillis()).thenReturn(2L);

    Calendar calenderend = Mockito.mock(Calendar.class);
    Mockito.when(calendarend.getTimeInMillis()).thenReturn(3L);

    Mockito.when(context.getParameter(ServiceConstants.TIMELINE_END)).thenReturn(calenderend);
    Mockito.when(context.getParameter(ServiceConstants.TIMELINE_BEGIN)).thenReturn(calenderstart);

    TestBaseTimelineProvider provider = new TestBaseTimelineProvider();
    boolean answer = provider.isDateWithinTimelineRange(calendertarget, context);

    assertNotNull(answer);
    assertTrue(provider.isDateWithinTimelineRange(calendartarget, context));
}
```

Secondly, you never actually wrote anything that tests for a false return.  To cover the other side, copy the above but set your `calendartarget.getTimeInMillis()` to return something ridiculous like `1000L` and change your assertions to reflect false.

You may also wish to break your test cases into multiple methods whose names reflect what each individual test method checks for, like `validDatesInRange()`, `validDatesNotInRange()`, `startDateIsNull()`, `endDateIsNull()`, `contextIsNull()`.  By doing so, your tests become smaller and easier to understand and debug, your test runs produce cleaner and far more informative test reports, and a failure in one test will not mask failures in others.

Comment: Thank you Brandon for the detailed post. I will definitely follow what you recommended.